# PHP Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

Please help. I cannot figure this out, and granted I am just learning php
I tried to add code to an existing woocommerce function, to remove a payment gateway if a group of products were in the cart.
I think the 4th line from the bottom "added for auto pay if statement" is the issue here. Thanks in advance.

```
public function is_available() {
    //added for autopay 1 line
    global $woocommerce;
    $is_available = parent::is_available();
    //added for autopay 2 lines
    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values )
    $autopays = array(26108,30619,35613);
    // don't show on checkout page
    if ( ! $this->is_express_checkout() && is_checkout() && ! $this->show_on_checkout() ) {
        $is_available = false;
    }

    // don't display when order review table is rendered via AJAX
    if ( ! $this->is_express_checkout() && defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX && isset( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'woocommerce_update_order_review' && ! $this->show_on_checkout() ) {
        $is_available = false;
    }

    // don't show on checkout > pay page
    if ( is_checkout_pay_page() ) {
        $is_available = false;
    }

    // don't show if the cart contains a subscription and manual renewals are not enabled
    if ( $this->get_plugin()->is_subscriptions_active() && WC_Subscriptions_Cart::cart_contains_subscription() && 'no' === get_option( WC_Subscriptions_Admin::$option_prefix . '_accept_manual_renewals', 'no' ) ) {
        $is_available = false;
    }
    //added for auto pay if statement
     if(in_array($values['product_id'],$autopays)){$is_available = false;
    }
    return $is_available;
}
```

Comment: $autopays has no value and it must be an array

Comment: I'm really sorry but I am pretty green. Are you saying that $autopays in if(in_array($values['product_id'],$autopays)) has no value. If that is the case, why do they not have a value if defined in 8th line?

Comment: are you really sure this is the code running on the server? the right file in the right location?

Comment: Yes, it is. The code actually works as intended, but it is flodding my error log.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/xI2fi5 this is completely valid, so something your not showing is going on here

Comment: can you test this: `if(in_array($values['product_id'],array(26108,30619,35613))){$is_available = false;
    } `

Comment: That is generating the same error in the error log.

PHP Notice: Undefined variable: values in wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express/includes/class-wc-gateway-paypal-express.php on line 473, referer: https://www.google.com/

Comment: `Undefined variable: values`  thats a NEW error. i dont see `$values` defined in that function

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I was getting both of those errors but now only getting the 1. I didn't notice at first because this is adding about 200 entries per minute to my error log.

Comment: well ok its simple there is no `$values` available in the function - so error

Comment: Not sure what's going on with your `foreach` loop, define `$autopays = array();` before the loop so it's always set regardless if there is no entries

Comment: foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) will this not work to define $values?

Comment: @gpratt86 where are your opening and closing conditions for the `foreach`?

Comment: @Bankzilla Sorry that is above me. I am not sure what I am missing there.

Comment: Which is line 473? Where does the new error point to?

Comment: @HareeshSivasubramanian

 if(in_array($values['product_id'],$autopays)){$is_available = false;

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value) {
    statement1...
    statement2... 
}
```

In your code, you're missing the opening and closing brackets after the foreach statement.